# How can change word into actual symbol in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe in which Symbols are written as word. I want to convert them into actual symbol so that python can easily understand the meaning and perform the action according that.

Example:

```
rulename       arg1            arg2
remove          CR
remove          LF
remove          SINGLEQUOTE
remove          DOUBLEQUOTE
remove          \"
replace         TAB            4Space
replace         3QUTOES        SINGLEQUOTE
replace         BACKSLASHPIPE  PIPE
replace         CR             LF
```

In output I want symbolic representation of arguments-

```
rulename        arg1           arg2
remove          \n\r
remove          \r\n
remove          '
remove          "
remove          \"
replace         '\t'           '    '
replace         "'''"          "'"
replace         '\|'           '|'
replace         '\n\r'         '\r\n'
```

and after converting like this, all the rules should apply on csv file one by one and do the changes.
Please help me how can I do this?

I tried this-

```
for index, row in df_rule_filter.iterrows():
            if(row['action'] == 'delimiter'):
                if(row['arg1'] == 'COMMA'):
                    df_input_file = pd.read_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/jgvcc/'+filename, delimiter=',')
                if(row['arg1'] == 'PIPE'):
                    df_input_file = pd.read_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/jgvcc/'+filename, delimiter='|')
            
            if(row['action'] == 'remove'):
                if(row['arg1'] == 'CTRLM'):
                    df_input_file = df_input_file.replace(r'\r', '', regex=True)

                if(row['arg1'] == 'LF'):
                    df_input_file = df_input_file.replace(r'\r\n', '', regex=True)

                if(row['arg1'] == 'CR'):
                    df_input_file = df_input_file.replace(r'\n', '', regex=True).replace(r'\r', '', regex=True)

                if(row['arg1'] == 'SINGLEQUOTE'):
                    df_input_file = df_input_file.replace(r"'", "", regex=True)

                if(row['arg1'] == 'DOUBLEQUOTE'):
                    df_input_file = df_input_file.replace(r'"', '', regex=True)

                if(row['arg1'] == 'BACKSLASH'):
                    df_input_file = df_input_file.replace(r'\\', '', regex=True)

            if(row['action'] == 'replace'):
                df_input_file = df_input_file.replace(str(row['arg1]), str(row['arg2']), regex=True)
```

Comment: @sushanth Please check again

Comment: "I tried this-" Okay, and what happened when you tried it? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 way is to replace values by creating a dictionary:

```
d={'CR':r'\r','LF':r'\n','SINGLEQUOTE':r"'",'DOUBLEQUOTE':r'"','TAB':r"'\t'","3QUTOES":r"'''","BACKSLASHPIPE":r"'\|'","4Space":r"'    '","PIPE":r"'|'","BACKSLASH":r"\\"}
#Add more element according to your need
```

Finally replace values by using `replace()` method:

```
df=df.replace(d,regex=True)
```

output:

```
rulename        arg1           arg2
remove          \r
remove          \n
remove          '
remove          "
remove          \"
replace         '\t'           '    '
replace         "'''"          "'"
replace         '\|'           '|'
replace         \r              \n
```

Notice that I updated `CR` and `LF` to reflect their *conventional* meanings. If you don't want that, maybe use different labels, so as not to confuse your readers (including your future self).

Comment: Maybe also fix or at least point the incorrect terminology: `LF` is `\n` and `CR` is `\r` and if you want to combine them, that's usually CR LF in that order.

Comment: @tripleee thanks sir for the suggestion but sir `CR` is `\n\r` and LF is `\r\n` according to OP's expected output..sorry If I was wrong !!

Comment: The problem is that their expectation is confused and incorrect. That's why I'm pointing it out. These are well-defined terms with a specific meaning.

Comment: @tripleee thanks sir for the advice..updated answer **:)**